# Mapping json in into ember model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i have custom url for getting and saving json from server so i created an object for getting json :

```
App.Cubes = Ember.Object.extend();
App.Cubes.reopenClass({
findAll: function() {
    var c = Ember.A();
    var xhr = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'http://localhost:9095/service.asmx/getCubes',
        data: '{}',
        success: function(response) {
            var data = JSON.parse(response.d);
            $.each(data, function(i, v) {
                c.pushObject(App.Cubes.create(v));
            });
        }

    });
    return c;
}
});
```

but i need to map these json to model like :

```
App.Cube = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
uniqueName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

and then using Cube model not using Cubes Object? but i dont know how to map these json or Cubes object to Cube model.it is important for me using ember-data not a simple ember object

Answer (score 0):

**Where is your controller code.**

```
App.CubeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        loadList: function(){
            var value = this.get('yourValue');
            if(value){
                this.set('model', App.Cubes.findAll(value))
            }
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: can i call loadList Action when one of my Ember.Select changed ? and pass the value of Ember.Select to loadList funciton.

Comment: @mamal: yes, you can pass the value.